# How can I create country code picker in the Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a country code picker in the Jetpack Compose, how can I create it?
Note: The list of country codes come from our server.

[image]

**when we clicked on it:**

[image]

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far ...

Comment: Provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Oh, there you are Perry.

Comment: I don't have any idea to implement this –

Answer (score -1):

you can use ComposeCountryCodePicker library

https://github.com/farhanroy/ComposeCountryCodePicker

like this

[image]
    
    
        [image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for Country Phone Code Picker for Jetpack Compose you can use the package.

https://github.com/togisoft/jetpack_compose_country_code_picker

[image]